# Generating random variables with complicated probability distribution functions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have an interesting question I need to solve, and as much as I try, I cannot wrap my head around it.

Given a postive random variable `X` with p.d.f. `f`, it can be proven if you generate a standard uniform value `U`, the value `a` will be a random variable with p.d.f. `f`, as given by the formula below:

$$ \int_0^a f(x) dx = U$$

I am told to use this relationship to write a function which generates values for the random variable `X` with p.d.f.:

$ f(x) = 4x^3 $ if $ 0 \le x < 1 $

Can someone be so kind as to point me in the direction I need to go to begin solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

first find the cumulative density function for the random variable $X$:
$$
\mbox{pdf}(x)=4x^3 \implies \mbox{cdf}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\mbox{pdf}(t)\mbox{dt}=x^4
$$
now let's find the inverse of the cumulative density function:
$$
\mbox{cdf}(x)=x^4 \implies \mbox{icdf}(x)=\sqrt[4]{x}
$$
let's sample a value in $\mbox{U}(0,1)$ and use the inv. cum. density function to get a random sample in $X$:
$$
u \sim \mbox{U}(0,1) \implies \mbox{icdf}(u) \sim X \iff  \sqrt[4]{u} \sim X
$$